# Which crypto-currencies can be mined effectively with GPU

Tags: altcoin, alternatives, gpu-mining, cpu-mining

We often hear both CPU and GPU mining are dead.

There is a number of new currencies designed specifically for CPU or GPU mining. Which are these? Can you mine them effectively with GPU?

Answer (score 2):

You can look at [litecoin](https://litecoin.org/). It is still feasible to mine it with CPU and GPU, because it is really hard to implement the algorithm in ASICs. And the price of litecoin is not bad.

Comment: Although GPU are still more efficient, even dor scrypt.

Comment: I have not told that you will be better with CPU. I just told that you can still mine and get some profit with CPU.

Comment: *GPU's and dor=for, can't edit typo anymore :). @Salvador Dali looking at [the scrypt performance comparison for hardware](https://litecoin.info/Mining_hardware_comparison) I'd say efficiency of CPU : GPU is as 1 : 10, so that makes quite a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I know you can mine Ethereum, Monero and Litecoin.